# How to fix AttributeError at /login/ 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, django, authentication, attributeerror

I am trying to create a **login form in Django**. In that form, there are 2 fields, username, and password for login. Now **I have used lower() at the time of getting the username.** Have a look at the code below. I have used lower() because if an user enters the upper case letter they don't have to face any problem.

**Here is the code**

```
def loginForm(request):
    page = 'login'
    if request.user.is_authenticated:    #if user is already login, restricted to visit the login page again
        return redirect('home')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username').lower()
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except:
            messages.error(request,'User does not exist')
        user = authenticate(request,username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Invalid Username or Password')

    context = {'page':page}
    return render(request, 'base/register_login.html',context)
```

here is the SS of the error..
[Screenshot of the error in the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWF1S.png)

Kindly let me know how can I solve this error..

Comment: share your template `register_login.html`

Comment: `.lower()` is a method of string, but the value of request.POST.get('username') you are getting after post is none.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `username` isn't in the data when you post data through to your view.

A simple way to fix this error is to set a different default value for `username` like so:

```py
username = request.POST.get('username', '').lower()
```